# YouTube iframe API - Video disappear

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I use this code show and manage YouTube videos on my site, but sometimes the video shows up just for 1 or 2 seconds and then disappear. Below what I use.

```
 function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(id_video) {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: '<?php echo $video['id_video'] ?>',
        playerVars:{'controls':0},
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide an example that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Sometimes when the page is loaded, the video disappear past 1/2 seconds. Not find a reason.